# What is the purpose of querying on "like '%%'"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application that has the following WHERE clause in one of its queries.

```
WHERE objId = 5 AND ( field1 like '%%' OR field2 like '%%' OR field3 like '%%')
```

Using MySQL's `EXPLAIN`  function, it doesn't seem to be looking for more rows than necessary (fortunately the index on `objId` filters out a lot of rows), but what is the point of checking whether a field is like `%%`?

Comment: A really poor way of making sure one of the three fields isn't `null`?

Comment: There is no purpose to querying with a like statement using "%%", it's the same as using "%".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that script which was generating this SQL has some variables between `%`, but they were empty, so there is an output `%%`.

Simply:

```
$var = '';
$sql = "... field LIKE '%" . $var . "%' OR ...";
```

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable situation, and looking further into it, the query is generated just like that.

Comment: Hopefully not just like that.. cause it is quite likely to allow sql code injection

Comment: Maybe situation is reasonable, but design pattern isn't ;-)

Comment: @odedsh You don't know that - maybe variables are handled in the proper way.

Comment: @odedsh yup just like that. I also thought "no sanitation?" but the rest of the application is littered with no concern for security either from what I'm seeing. The input comes directly from text boxes on the application.

Answer (score 5):

`like '%%'` / `like '%'`  are the same empty condition. (accepts every value except NULL)

It is likely that the code behind is something like:

`WHERE objId = ? AND ( field1 like '%?%' OR field2 like '%?%' OR field3 like '%?%')`

And you just happen to send it without any actual filter values.. (empty strings for all filter conditions)